# Solidity contract using delegation working well in remix vm shanghai environment but failing in our local node

Tags: delegatecall

We have a contract that use a delgatecall to finally register a node in a mapping array (nodeDB contract).
This contracts works correctly if we executed in remix vm shanghai environment but if we executed them in our local ethereum node, delegatecall returns false.
Same smart contracts works correctly in remix shanghai vm environment but fails if we execute it in our local node.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
import "./Address.sol";
import "./SafeMath.sol";


contract Proxy {
    using Address for address;
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    address private nodeLogicAddress;
    address private OrdersAddress;

    constructor (address nodeLogic, address Orders) public {
        nodeLogicAddress = nodeLogic;
        OrdersAddress = Orders;
    }

     function delegate(bytes memory payload) public returns (bool, bytes memory) {
        (bool ok, bytes memory pay) = OrdersAddress.delegatecall(payload);
        return (ok, pay);
    }
   }
```

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "./NodeDB.sol";
import "./NodeLogic.sol";
import "./Address.sol";


contract Orders {
    using Address for address;
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    address private nodeLogicAddress;
    function addNewNode(address key, uint plantId, uint nodeType, uint prodOrdered, uint produced, uint consOrdered, uint consumed) public   {
        NodeLogic(nodeLogicAddress).addNode(key, plantId, nodeType, prodOrdered, produced, consOrdered, consumed);
    }

    }
```

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "./NodeDB.sol";

contract NodeLogic {
    address public nodeDBAddress; 
    constructor(address nodeDB) public {
        nodeDBAddress = nodeDB;
    }
    function addNode (address pubKey, uint plantId, uint nodeType, uint accProdOrdered, uint accProdMeasured, uint accConsOrdered, uint accConsMeasured) external 
     {
        NodeDB(nodeDBAddress).addNode(pubKey, plantId, nodeType, accProdOrdered, accProdMeasured, accConsOrdered, accConsMeasured);
    }

   }
```

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "./SafeMath.sol";
import "./GLStructs.sol";

contract NodeDB {
    using SafeMath for uint256; 
    mapping(address => GLStructs.Node) private nodes; 
    function addNode(address pubKey, uint plantId, uint nodeType, uint accProdOrdered, uint accProdMeasured, uint accConsOrdered, uint accConsMeasured) external {
        nodes[pubKey] = GLStructs.Node(pubKey, plantId, nodeType, accProdOrdered, accProdMeasured, accConsOrdered, accConsMeasured);
    }

    function existsNode(address key) public view returns (bool) {
        return (nodes[key].pubKey == key);
    }

}
```